# learning svn for experienced git users?

Tags: svn, git

I'm looking for "more than an introduction" to subversion for someone like me who is by far most comfortable with git and passingly competent with subversion and looking to learn more advanced subversion use. Preferably something 'faster' than reading Practical Subversion.

Comment: There are some arenas where it is hard to translate bitter experience into readable prose. I suspect VCS is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some advanced topics can be found here:

http://subversion.apache.org/docs/community-guide/

Comment: That seems to be more about working on Subversion itself rather than using it. Has the web page changed in the last 3 years?